# iText library on Raspberry

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, itext, raspberry-pi2

I have created a java project to export some information in PDF format. I have used  the library called : itext 5.1.1 . When I run this poject on Windows, it works very good, but when I move it on my Raspberry it doesn't work. If I open the terminal, I go to java project folder, I write this:

```
java -cp "itext5.1.1.jar" . ExportPDF_Main.class
```

the terminal return this error message:

```
Error: could not find or load main class
```

If I open the terminal, I go to java project folder, I write this:

```
java -cp . ExportPDF_Main
```

the terminal return this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/itextpdf/text/Phrase
```

I think that this library doesn't work on Raspberry, in your opinion what's the problem?
I hope in your response. Have good time. Thanks for the attention.

Comment: Hi! I work at iText Software, and outside of work I am also a Raspberry Pi enthousiast. You can use the full Java SE on a RasPi, so there's no reason why iText wouldn't work out of the box. So I don't think your problem is RasPi-specific. Have you tried on a regular Linux desktop pc? I also think that we'll need to see your code, to be able to help you out. I would also recommend that you do not use iText `5.1.1` but `5.5.9` (or `5.5.10`, if you wait one more week). Or use iText `7.0.1`, but then you would need to change your code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks mate. It work so good also on my raspberry now. I sovled it write on linux terminal :

```
java -cp .:/home/pi/Desktop/Poject/Library/* ExportPDF_Main
```

I must include all libraries in my project

Comment: So it was a classpath issue. Typical Java stuff. It requires you to be very specific about your classpath. :)